# OS X application crashes when installed from pkg but copying the .app folder runs fine

Tags: osx-mavericks, pkgbuild, install.packages

I created a .pkg installer using Iceberg on OS X.

The installer runs fine, but when I try to run the installed application, it crashes within a couple seconds.

However if I take the same .app folder from the XCode build and copy it in the Finder to the Applications folder, the application runs fine and does not crash.

So the only difference is the copy method. From the .pkg installer the app crashes. If I just do a simple copy, the application runs fine.

In Iceberg, I even turned off "compress" in the archiving options to see if that was causing problems.

Can you think of any reason why the .PKG .app folder would be different?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It was a permissions problem, although I am not sure why.

Basically the installer pkg was set to copy everything with 755 permissions. Even though none of the files in the .app folder need write access in my code, I guess OS X must need group write permissions on some of the files.

Once I changed everything in the install to 775 permissions, the app started working fine. But with 755, the app would crash/exit right away.

Anyone know if there are certain system files in an application that need group write permissions?